# Apache Airflow problem - "a task with task_id create_tag_template_field_result is already in the DAG"

Tags: airflow

So, I have a problem with even the blank Airflow installation.

As soon as I try to run

```
airflow test tutorial print_date 2015-06-01
```

I get a raised exception which says

**PendingDeprecationWarning: The requested task could not be added to the DAG because a task with task_id create_tag_template_field_result is already in the DAG. Starting in Airflow 2.0, trying to overwrite a task will raise an exception.**

What is the reason for this (as I made literally no changes to the installation whatsoever)?

I also got that when, in a previous installation, I tried to run my own dag... but the "create_tag_template_field_result" was nowhere to be found in my code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can set the config arg load_examples = False to solve it.

This is the test command will call get_dag function which will construct a DagBag object, in the construction function will call collect_dags function.
The collect_dags function when the conf arg LOAD_EXAMPLES=True(default True), will collect all the dags in the example path, that's where the task create_tag_template_field_result comes from.
And in the collect_dags function will call add_task function of every example task, that's where you add the create_tag_template_field_result task again.
And maybe it's quickstart when you added this task before for the first time while you didn't realize.
you can set the config arg load_examples = False to solve it

Answer (score 1):

This warning is occuring in
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/airflow/example_dags/example_complex.py
so i remove  or rename (for example, to not working name *.py.back ) this.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error with a fresh install.

Then I don't know if this helps, but I downgraded Airflow to version 1.10.10 (with python3.7) and the error was gone.

Comment: It's not a solution but evades the problem.